# Vpn setup for remote access of offline nvr

Tags: vpn, nas, remote-access, remote-connection

My objective is remote online access of nvr or nas which is not allowed internet access through router settings.

Im imagining using my router quickvpn/ l2tp/ pptp options to access nvr.
When internet is disabled to a device, lan is still working, but will router vpn get me access to the nvr/ nas which has internet only disabled?

I want offline nvr due to it being chinese brand. My router is dlink, nvr is tplink. Both consumer grade

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried? Whether it is possible depends on the capabilities of the NVR/NAS, or the systems you can connect it to. Regardless, this question needs A) more information, and B) more info about what you've researched and tried.

Comment: Which router (brand/model) are you using and how have you disabled Internet access from the NVR?

Comment: Dlink routers have option on the status page to disable internet to each user but lan still working. This way im planing to disable internet to my nvr or nas. But will i be able to connect through from router vpn from outside